# How can I run Pipeline in old Directory if I have a new Directory?

Tags: azure-devops

I have 2 Directory. At Directory A, I have data and I have Pipeline in Azure DevOps. At Directory B, I migrate all of data from Directory A to Directory B. At Directory A, my Pipeline is died because I migrate the data from Directory A to B. So can I run pipeline at Directory A when I am at Directory B ?

I have 2 Directory. At directory A, I built the data and now I want to migrate all my data from directory A to B. But the data at directory A relate the Pipeline. I image that Is there a way to run a pipeline on directory A even though the data is in directory B.

Comment: Hi @dat nguyen, is the answer below to check out multiple repos helps you? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to run a pipeline on directory A even though the data
> is in directory B.

You could [check out multiple repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline with service connection. In the following example, the Azure Repos Git repository in another organization is declared as repository resources and requires service connections that is specified as the endpoint for the repository resource. This example has two checkout steps, which checks out the repository declared as repository resource along with the current self-repository that contains the pipeline YAML.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository # In a different organization
    endpoint: MyAzureReposGitServiceConnection
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo
    ref: main
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository
```

Then, create Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server service connection with configuration like below.

[image]